# how to proguard prevent from stripping array

Tags: android-proguard

I have implemented gooeymenu in a layout file:

```
<com.mschwartz.dailyflightbuddy.ui.GooeyMenu
    android:id="@+id/gooeymenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/btn_text_cockpit"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    app:center_drawable="@drawable/ic_settings_white_48dp"
    app:hide_on_start="true"
    app:itemorientation="LEFT"
    app:menu_reference="@array/gooeymenu_command_array" />
```

The `menu_reference` tag points to a file `res/values/array.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<array name="gooeymenu_command_array">

    <item>@drawable/gooey_info_item</item>
    <item>@drawable/gooey_zoom_item</item>
    <item>@drawable/gooey_center_item</item>
    <item>@drawable/gooey_city_item</item>
    <item>@drawable/gooey_airport_item</item>
    <item>@drawable/gooey_configure_item</item>
</array>

</resources>
```

When running in the debugger everything works fine but when running from the stripped production version gooeymenu does not show any items.

I have tried to add several commands to `proguard-rules.pro` including the following:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.mschwartz.dailyflightbuddy.R$array {
    *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
     public static <fields>;
}
```

but without any luck so far. So my questions are:

- How can I verify if the fields have really been stripped from the
  production apk or how can I make sure if a field (or more common a class/method) is included?
- How can I command proguard to add the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I use an `ObjectAnimator` which changes the property of an object by referencing the method by its name:

'ObjectAnimator animShowAlpha = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(circlePoint, "Alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f);'

proguard however mangles the names of the objects and hence the method `CirclePoint.setAlpha(..)` was renamed to `a(..)`. So the solution was to add a line to proguard to prevent renaming the methods of the class `CirclePoint`:

`-keep class com.mschwartz.dailyflightbuddy.ui.GooeyMenu$CirclePoint { *; }`

That's it.

btw. To see if proguard renames a method or not the file '*app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt*' is of great help (and self-explanatory).